# Capybara has_css? passing when it should fail

Tags: ruby, capybara

Why does the following step pass:

```
page.has_css?("doesnt exist")
```

when this correctly fails:

```
page.should have_css("doesnt exist")
```

If I run:

```
puts page.has_css?("doesnt exist")
```

it prints "false", but the step still passes.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably have:

```
assert page.has_css?("doesnt exist")
```

If you write "2 == 3" in a test, it will evaluate to false, but the test method will not necessarily fail.  You need an assert.  I think the "should" style syntax are doing some kind of assert under the hood as well.

Comment: Sounds right to me, but I'm getting an "undefined method 'assert'" error for that, is there something I need to include to get that working?

Comment: No, there wasn't anything extra I included to get my assertions working.  Try another form of assert: asssert_equal true, page.has_css?("doesnt exist")

Comment: Ok - got it working, needed to include the Test::Unit::Assertions module.  Thanks for your help, your solution is correct.

Comment: I, too, found this confusing at first, but it appears that the call to `page.has_css?("whatever")` is only _a query method_ as detailed on the [README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#querying). Query methods are for "querying the page for the existence of certain elements, and working with and manipulating those elements."  So you ask the page if something exists, but your "test method" is merely asking a question (as @coder_tim mentions) -- not checking that the given answer matches an expectation.